Trouble installing R-INLA
I am trying to install R-INLA but when I run the following code:
install.packages("INLA",repos=c(getOption("repos"),INLA="https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/stable"), dep=TRUE)

I get the following error message:
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘INLAspacetime’ is not available

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
       binary   source needs_compilation
INLA 22.04.16 24.02.09             FALSE

installing the source package ‘INLA’

trying URL 'https://inla.r-inla-download.org/R/stable/src/contrib/INLA_24.02.09.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 81844375 bytes (78.1 MB)
downloaded 78.1 MB

* installing *binary* package 'INLA' ...
cp: unknown option -- )
Try '/usr/bin/cp --help' for more information.
ERROR: installing binary package failed
* removing 'C:/Users/OneDrive - /Documents/R/win-library/4.1/INLA'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘INLA’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpg9csor\downloaded_packages’

Any ideas what the problem is?

Try running install.packages("INLAspacetime") first. What version of R are you using? That package does require R ≥ 4.3. You may just need to update your R.
